# What should I do about a bad drywall job on the ceiling?

Tags: drywall

I started to try and cover the tape marks with more joint compound, I was going to sand it, but now I think I should scrape all of it off and try to redo it.  It’s absolutely driving me mad.

[image]

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: Follow the method here, especially the "don't try to make it perfect when wet" part. Most inexperienced folks waste a lot of time and effort trying to lay on a perfect coat, often on hopes of being done in one go - don't. https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/93960/18078

Answer (score 3):

The usual approach is indeed to scrape to a sensible point and respray. If you're going with acoustical texture again you don't have to skim first if it comes off fairly cleanly.

You can rent a texture sprayer and do it yourself. Practice first to be sure you have a suitable mix and an understanding of how distance and pattern will affect the outcome.

Above all, start thin and build up. More texture is not necessarily better texture, and you can't take it back once it's on there. :)

Answer (score 2):

Even if you remove your patch work, sand it and start over, you'll still have a hard time matching the texture with the rest of the ceiling. I doubt you're going to want to sand the entire ceiling smooth and then repaint. Your other option would be to repair the bad drywall job and then repaint the ceiling with a textured paint. That would give you a uniform surface.